# How can I consume a (rust) `.wasm` lib in wasmedge_quickjs?

Tags: webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'd like to make an isomorphic wasm library that can be consumed both in the browser and wasmedge-quickjs.

To do this, I have a simple demo lib:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}
```

For the browser, this is pretty straight forward: I run `wasm-pack build --target web` to generate my output and consume as such:

```js
import init, { add } from "/rs_lib.js";

init().then(() => console.log(add(1, 2));
```

This works just fine.

Where I'm struggling is for wasmedge. Unfortunately it doesn't implement the `WebAssembly` global which you'd use in Node, and it has no way of directly consuming the `.wasm` as you might see in a bundler. How am I meant to be consuming this?

```js
// ReferenceError: could not load module filename 'rs-lib/pkg-bundler/rs_lib_bg.wasm'
import * as tmp from '../rs-lib/pkg-node/rs_lib.js';
```

```js
// ReferenceError: 'WebAssembly' is not defined
//    at <anonymous> (rs-lib/pkg-node/rs_lib.js:20)
import * as tmp from '../rs-lib/pkg-node/rs_lib.js';
```

Comment: It seems that you are too early? In this issue[1], specifically this comment [2], it seems that wasmedge-quickjs is meant to implement the full node api. According to the linked deno document, the WebAssembly global (missing from [1]) should be a part of it. I suggest you post a question there as well?

In the mean time, can you run your wasm module with Wasmedge proper? Not with wasmedge-quickjs

[1] https://github.com/WasmEdge/WasmEdge/issues/1535

[2] https://github.com/WasmEdge/WasmEdge/issues/1535#issuecomment-1902112619

Comment: Gotcha, fair enough. This isn't a Node API, gets into WinterCG (web interoperable runtime) as the `WebAssembly` global exists outside of Node too. Bit unfortunate then, guess will just have to wait.